# RXJS - EXCEPTION: Rx is not defined, ng 2

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have an angular2 service which makes an API call and then returns an observable, but, RXJS is returning an error saying EXCEPTION: Rx is not defined. What else do I need to import? Surely I don;'t need to import the whole folder?

!--- imports

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

!--- service code

```
  const server = 'http://api.myserver.com';
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(this.requestJson());

    let s = this._http.get(`${server}`);
    s.flatMap(s => {
      let theRes = JSON.parse(s._body);
      return Rx.Observable.from(theRes); <--- happens right here
    }).filter(function(data) {
      console.log('all array ' + data);
      return true;
    }).subscribe(function (v) {
      console.log(v);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Rx.Observable`, `Observable` alone will do. And add:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

**Update**: The Angular CLI has improved tree shaking since I posted this answer, you should definitely always import from it's own module:

```
import {Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs' // is okay
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable' // much better
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription' // much better
```